# PHP comparing strings from two separate arrays using stripos

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays that i need to loop through and compare strings. My question is what would be the best way to do this because when I use `stripos()` it fails (no matches found) but just using `if($a1 == $a2){}` it works fine.

So here's the code using `stripos()`:

```
foreach(array_combine($import_data['item_id'], $import_data['title']) as $item_id => $title) {
  foreach($unlinked as $product) {
    if(stripos($title, $product['title'] !== false)) {
      echo $product['title'] . '<br>';
      echo $item_id . ' - ' . $product['product_id'] . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

But changing the if statement to

```
if($product['title'] == $title) {}
```

It then works fine. So, is it OK to compare strings using this method or is there a more accurate way of comparing strings in PHP.

Comment: You've got the paramters backwards. It should be: `stripos(haystack, needle)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the result is zero OR false. It's not the same thing. Zero means "I've found it at location zero".

Comment: @dkeliner So this worked `if (stripos($title, $product['title']) !== false || stripos($title, $product['title']) === 0) {}` Would this be the best way or is it ok to just compare with `==`. They both find the same matches but havent done much testing with them.

Comment: I will use `if($ar1 === $ar2) {}`. I believe it will be faster and just as accurate. Thanks, for the help. Just needed a little more learning about string comparison in PHP.